# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page. on magento admin login page

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.9

I have a weird situation again that I have encountered on Magento. A few hours ago, I successfully logged in to admin dashboard. After I logged out and restart my pc and tried to log in again. I got an error

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Magento was installed on a live server. I didn't change anything or add something to the database. Credentials are valid but we cannot log in. Also, I cannot login to the Magento downloader panel.

What kind of bug is this?

How can we solve this?

**UPDATE!**

From @DouglasRadburn link. The detailed explanation of the problem and the possible solutions.

> https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98236#98236

Also similar to @Makwana Ketan answer

Comment: In SUPEE7405 (included in 1.9.2.3), admin login form has a formkey added - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/98220/security-patch-supee-7405-possible-problems/98236#98236

Comment: Thanks @DouglasRadburn for sharing this link. This helps a lot.

Comment: i have magento 1.9.2.4,I face the same error only in ubuntu OS, but in window 7 its working good.do you have any other idea

Answer (score 5):

I am sure that problems came from session storage & cookie setting.

You should follow below:

```
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';

DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';
```

Delete all directories from below folders:

```
/var/session
/var/cache
```

Answer (score 3):

***While working on localhost can not sign in or create Account - ubuntu OS***

> Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

**invalid key error solve**

> change this value in your php.ini file

max_input_time : 3600
max_input_vars : 200000
memory_limit : 2G

> *then  go to your MySQL database*

find core_config_data table

**change base URL localhost to 127.0.0.1**

than **search**  path Like %...% domain then Go

**change** value *localhost* to *127.0.0.1* in front of *web/cookie/cookie_domain* ( path )

> Go to your magento root directory
>   then app -> /etc/ -> env.php open this file
>   change value localhost to 127.0.0.1 ( 2 places in file )

*go to browser press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd> then check cache || cookie click on **clear data***

> then run all command with sudo on magento root directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: For me it was a simple memory_limit increase as suggested here.

Comment: for increase max_input_time  and max_input_vars value because some time form that you submit contains a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having this issue in my localhost after using production DB. I tried setting up max_input_vars but that didn't work. But clearing cookie settings such cookie path and domain works. So, go to stores -> configuration then General —> Web —> Default Cookie settings and remove values for cookie path and domain. Then clear magento2 configuration cache using bin/magento cache:clean config. This should resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Browser, Clear cookies and session data. for safety clear your cache by `bin/magento c:c`, then refresh the browser page.

Answer (score 0):

If the db is copied from the other server, just create a new admin user. The issue will resolve

Answer (score -7):

Please ask hosting provider to increase php_value `max_input_vars 75000`.

Comment: 75,000 var limit? That is absolutely insane. Might as well make it a million then.

Comment: I have set max_input_vars 7500 and 1 million, but still face the same error

Comment: This is not working and I don't think so is a valid solution

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it